# How to create an id for a td element based on the row id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I'm trying to generate the id of a td element, based on it's row number.

I believe that the td id must be unique. Maybe I am wrong?
I'm therefore trying to concatenate the row number with some text but can't seem to get it to work.

We are using jQuery on our website and I can successfully create other id's which are based on variables, but i'm a little stuck on this one. Here's an example of something that works

```
<td id="person-id${person.id}">${person.name}</td>
```

The html will later look something like:

```
<td id="person1"></td><td id="person2"></td><td id="person3"></td> etc
```

I was hoping to do something like this for another table but having some trouble:

```
<td id="row-number("+rowIndex+")">some text here</td>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do they need to be `id`s?

Comment: Are you trying to do it with JQuery or JSTL? with both of them you can easily iterate on whatever you want and set its id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to assign the id based on column number, not row number.  If I'm correct in this assumption, you can do it with jQuery like so:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
 $(this).children().each(function() {
 var n = $(this).index();
 $(this).attr('id','person'+n);
 });
});
```

Otherwise, if you do want the row number assigned to the id, it would be:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
 $(this).children().each(function() {
 var n = $(this).parent().index();
 $(this).attr('id','person'+n);
 });
});
```

Voila.